# Laravel dynamic URL routing

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, routes

I am relatively new with Laravel and taking it on myself to learn some new technologies and platforms. I am loving Laravel's routing features and just wondering if there was a way to route to resources within a route group dynamically.

```php
Route::group(['domain' => 'api.domain.dev', 'prefix' => '/{version}/{resource}'],
    function ($ignore, $version = 'v1', $resource = 'test') {
        // Check if resource exists, if not 404
        $path = '../app/Http/Controllers/api/'.$version.'/'.$resource.'Controller.php';
        if (!File::exists($path)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        // Add magic method __get to handle errors and use interface to ensure all methods are available
        Route::get('', "api\\{$version}\\{$resource}Controller@index");
        Route::put('', "api\\{$version}\\{$resource}Controller@put");
        Route::post('', "api\\{$version}\\{$resource}Controller@post");
        Route::delete('', "api\\{$version}\\{$resource}Controller@delete");
    }
);
```

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is to route all API subdomains into a group. Then use a version number to route to a group of controllers dynamically, these will be split by folder name.

**Example URL**

> http://api.domain.com/v1/test

Answer (score 0):

To create dynamic URL routing in Laravel with versioning, namespaces, and prefixes, you can use the group method in your routes/api.php file.

```
Route::middleware(APIversion::class)->prefix('{version}/{device}')->group(function () {
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api\\'.request()->route('version').'\\'], function () {
        Route::controller(AuthController::class)->group(function(){
            Route::post('/login',['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'login']);
        });
    });
});
```

That should work.